# $a_k = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}a_i \left(\frac{1}{k-i}-\frac{1}{k-i+1}\right)$ and $a_1 = 1$, prove the series is decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, monotone-functions

If the series {$a_n$} is defined recursively in the following way:

1. $a_1 = 1$,
2. $a_k = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}a_i\cdot\left(\frac{1}{k-i}-\frac{1}{k-i+1}\right)$ for $k=2,\cdots, n$,

how can I prove that $a_k$ is decreasing?

Comment: idk, have you tried induction? or induction on a stronger statement than that the $a_k$'s are decreasing

Comment: I tried induction for $a_{k+1}-a_k$ and $a_{k+1}/a_k$, but I always got stuck somewhere since the formulation inside the summation is not always negative...

Comment: Shouldn't it be "$\geq$" direction for the first inequality?

Comment: oops. confused myself. thanks. idk, try to prove $a_k \le a_{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}$ or something like that via induction

Comment: I've been struggling on this one for a month... thanks for the ideas anyway!

Comment: have you tried finding an explicit, closed form for the $a_k$'s?

Comment: Yes, I tried but failed to find an explicit form.

Comment: @ermao Rewrite the fractions in the bracket as a single fraction. Then combine terms in $a_k-a_{k+1}$ in a sum up to $k-1$ (multiplying by a convenient 1), adding the remaining terms separately and using induction on them, while claiming that the sum part is also positive.

Comment: @ermao I've spent quite a bit of time trying to solve this interesting problem. So far, by adding the summations for $a_j$ for $j = 1$ to $k$ & using the telescoping series for each $a_i$ to simplify the sums, I rewrote it as $\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{a_i}{k-i+1} = 1$. From this, due to the harmonic series sum diverging, the greatest lower bound is $0$, i.e., $a_k$ is at least generally decreasing. For first $5$ differences at least, $a_i - a_{i+1} \ge \frac{1}{2i(i+1)}$, but I wasn't able to show it's always true. If any of this is new & you'd like more details, I can write an answer to give them.

Comment: @JohnOmielan "but I wasn't able to show it's always true". if you know how to do basic computer programming, you can test whether it's true for many $i$

Comment: @AnyAD Yes, I tried that one. Unfortunately, the coefficient of $a_i$ inside the sum is not always positive. Actually, it is negative almost for every i... Thanks for the thinking anyway!

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks for the ideas! I checked using matlab, your claim works for very large n. At least it provides a lower bound describing how $a_i$ decays.

Comment: @ermao I don't know which term you are talking about.

Comment: @mathworker21 I deleted my earlier comment as I believe it unnecessarily stating my long period & # of years of programming experience may have come across as being "snarky". I apologize if it seemed that way to you. As ermao has confirmed, my observation of $a_i - a_{i+1}\ge\frac{1}{2i(i+1)}$ holds for large $i$. As just a lower bound for the differences doesn't seem sufficient for induction, I unsuccessfully tried to find an upper bound to use inductively to prove the lower bound of the next difference, & vice versa. I may use a program to write various values to check other possibilities.

Comment: @JohnOmielan no problem lol. I tried the same thing, i.e. proving upper and lower bounds inductively. seems you need very tight bounds to do so successfully...

Comment: @JohnOmielan Hi John. There's been some fun stuff happening [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3604480/how-to-prove-this-inequality-x2-n-le-frac83). I wonder if any of those methods will be useful for this problem (the one I'm commenting on). I'm not too comfortable with those methods yet. But I want to point out that the equation you pointed out in an above comment of yours, $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{n-i+1} = 1$ can be written as $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{a_{i+1}}{1-\frac{i}{n}}\frac{1}{n} = 1$, which feels like $\int_0^1 \frac{a_t}{1-t}dt = 1$, which makes 'decreasing' plausible..

Comment: @mathworker21 Thanks for the additional information. I've looked at it and believe it may be helpful, but I also am not sure about that yet.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Got it! (finally)

Answer (score 2):

Let $F(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k x^k$ for $x \in (-1,1)$ (convergence is clear).

Claim: We have $F(x) = \frac{x}{(1-x^{-1})\log(1-x)}$ for $x \in (-1,1)$.

> Proof: We have $F(x) = x+\sum_{k=2}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} a_j \frac{1}{(k-j)(k-j+1)}x^k = x+\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j x^j \sum_{k=j+1}^\infty \frac{x^{k-j}}{(k-j)(k-j+1)}$. Note the inner sum is $\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{x^r}{r(r+1)}$, so $F(x) = x+\left(\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{x^r}{r(r+1)}\right)F(x)$. The identity $1-\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{x^r}{r(r+1)} = (1-x^{-1})\log(1-x)$ thus gives the result. $\square$

Now, since $(1-x^{-1})F(x) = -1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (a_k-a_{k+1})x^k$, we see $\frac{x}{\log(1-x)} = -1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (a_k-a_{k+1})x^k$ for $x \in (-1,1)$. Changing $x \mapsto -x$, we have, for $x \in (-1,1)$, $$\frac{x}{\log(1+x)} = 1-\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k(a_k-a_{k+1})x^k.$$ We wish to prove $(-1)^k \frac{\partial^k}{\partial x^k}\left[\frac{x}{\log(1+x)}\right]\Big|_{x=0} \le 0$ for all $k \ge 0$. It then suffices to show $(-1)^k \frac{\partial^k}{\partial x^k}\left[\frac{x}{\log(1+x)}\right] \le 0$ on all of $[0,\infty)$, i.e., that $\frac{x}{\log(1+x)}$ is a [Bernstein function](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Bernstein_function). But this follows from the fact that $\log(1+x)$ is a [complete Bernstein function](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Bernstein_function#Examples) together with the [general result](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Operator_monotone_function#Properties) that $x/f(x)$ is a (complete) Bernstein function if $f(x)$ is.