# How to prove this inequality $x^2_{n}\le\frac{8}{3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

let sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ such $x_{1}=0,x_{2}=1$,and 
$$x_{n+1}=\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)x_{n}-x_{n-1},n\ge 2$$
show that
$$x^2_{n}\le\dfrac{8}{3}$$

This problem it seem interesting,and 
$$x_{n+1}-x_{n}=\dfrac{1}{n}x_{n}-x_{n-1}$$
so we have
$$x_{n+1}-x_{1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{x_{k}}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}x_{k}$$
 where $x_{0}=-1$

It seem this problem very interesting,I guess this $\dfrac{8}{3}$ maybe is not best constant,But is stronger constant

Comment: Hey,it's very interesting.I've made attempts to explore this problem for an hour, but have no methods.

Comment: Thanks, This problem is from my teacher give me

Comment: Does anyone have a computer that's more powerful than a macbook laptop? I have a python code and am trying to plot $x_n^2$ (and I seem to have discovered something interesting), but I don't have enough power to see enough pattern to support my claim lol.

Comment: Sneak peak of what I've done so far: https://imgur.com/a/mu4Zg2f
I should note that the x-axis is not n, but rather n*5000. So 20000 -> 1e8
And since I'm only plotting a_(n*5000) it might differ from a_n. I doubt that though.
 As you can see it goes up and down like smoothly

Comment: My friends made some attempts to analysis the asymptotic property of $a_{6n}$, but had no idea about the bound 8/3.

Comment: Did your teacher give the answer？

Comment: Maybe you can formulate strong inequalities on $x_n$ and prove them by induction.

Comment: @mathworker21 Can you show the details？

Comment: @RocHang I haven't done that, just an idea

Comment: Maybe a trivial observation. $x_{n+1}=x_n-x_{n-1}$ with the specified initial conditions takes periodically only values between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: @Thomas Could you show the details？

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just so this question is fully answered (i.e. getting the bound $8/3$) here I add a condensed proof of $x_n^2 \leq \frac{8}{3}$ from the answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3615062/147873) as Community Wiki.

---

Define 
$$E_n = (x_n - x_{n-1})^2 + F_n\left(x_n + x_{n-1}\right)^2$$ 
with $F_n = \frac{(n-1)}{3n+1}$. The recurrence relation gives us
$$E_{n+1} - E_n = \frac{(F_{n+1}-F_n)}{F_n}\cdot F_n\left(x_n + x_{n+1}\right)^2 \geq 0$$
since $F_n$ is a positive and increasing function. This shows that $E_n$ is increasing. We also see that
$$E_{n+1} - E_n \leq \frac{(F_{n+1}-F_n)}{F_n}\cdot E_n \implies \frac{E_{n+1}}{F_{n+1}} \leq \frac{E_n}{F_n}$$
so $\frac{E_n}{F_n}$ is decreasing and since $F_n$ converges it follows that $E_n$ converges. To bound $x_n$ from $E_n$ note that the definition of $E_n$ (the equation for an ellipse) allows us to write $x_n - x_{n-1} = \sqrt{E_n}\cos(\phi_n)$ and $x_n + x_{n-1} = \sqrt{\frac{E_n}{F_n}}\sin(\phi_n)$ for some angle $\phi_n$. Thus

$$x_n^2 = \frac{E_n}{4}[\cos(\phi_n) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{F_n}}\sin(\phi_n)]^2$$
Maximizing the right hand side over $\phi_n$ gives us
$$x_n^2 \leq \frac{E_n}{4}\left[1 + \frac{1}{F_n}\right] = E_n\cdot \frac{n}{n-1}$$
Since $\frac{E_n}{F_n}$ is decreasing we have $E_n \leq F_n \frac{E_2}{F_2} = 8F_n$ and
$$x_n^2 \leq \frac{8n}{3n+1} \leq \frac{8}{3}$$
It is possible to improve the constant with a bit of numerical computation (using $n=5$ instead of $n=2$ when bounding $E_n$) to the best possible one $\frac{9}{4}$ (for which we have equality for $n=3$). The best possible asymptotic bound would be slightly smaller than $2$ (best possible in the sense that $x_n^2 \approx 2$ would occur infinitely many times).

Comment: This might not be relevant, but according to numerical calculation, $x_n^2=1.96+t<1.97$ is the best I've gotten

Comment: @GarethMa That is in good agreement with this. The absolute best asymptotic bound (i.e. that holds for very large $n$) we can get from this is $\sim 1.9735$.

Comment: The best low-res picture: https://imgur.com/a/mu4Zg2f

Comment: Also just wondering, how would 1.9735 be achieved? Like is there a closed form?

Comment: @GarethMa To get that one needs to numerically evaluate $x_n$ (to get $E_n$) up to some high $n$ and then apply the bounds here.

Comment: So we want a better bound for $\frac{E_n}{F_n}$ correct? which can be obtained with more calculation. But let's say if I calculate that for $n=10^6$, would the obtained bound just be $max(x_n^2 \forall 1\leq n \leq 10^6)$? Or would be obtain a better bound.

Comment: @GarethMa All I said is that *if* you wanted to find the best asymptotic bound (i.e. a bound for very large $n$) *then* you would do that. However the question only asks for $8/3$ which we get directly and since $x_2^2 = 9/4$ the best bound that holds for all $n$ (which is what the question asks for) is $9/4$ and you can get that with using the value for $E_n/F_n$ for $n=6$ or so (and you would have to check the value of $x_n^2$ for $n\leq 6$).

Comment: Sorry for asking so many questions, but like looking at the graph linked above, there seems to be a pattern - it goes up then down in a weird way. Is there an explanation to that? I also find another pattern, seen here: https://pastebin.com/NUNZ8cs4. The signs of the terms seem to alternate every 3 terms, and when $n \not \equiv 1 \mod 3$, $|x_n| < 1$ - is there also a proof for that? Sorry if it's trivial or anything, but I can't see the immediate reason.

Comment: Also bound program - https://repl.it/repls/VagueDecentCylinder. Press "Start" and it will non-stop give values - until the online platform stops it of course. Seems to be $<1.97351146$

Comment: @GarethMa The equivalent continuous problem (the recurrence relation is a discretisation of a differential equation) has solution $\sim \cos(w t)$ so it oscillates up and down. We only sample it on a grid of regular spaced points so we will not always hit the tops and bottoms of the $\cos$ curve. This is what mainly creates that effect (try to plot $\sin(n)$ for integer $n$ and you will see patterns).

Comment: Why does the period keep increasing then?

Comment: That is a combination of several effects: e.g. the frequency is not exactly constant which leads to a slow phase drift (try to change $1+1/n$ to $1+1/n^2$ and you will see it converge to $6$ lines very quickly, the solution for large $n$ is roughly $A\cos(2\pi n /6 + \phi)$).

Comment: Thank you so much for this and your time. It really helps with understand the information.

Comment: can you explain why think about the $E_{n}=(x_{n}-x_{n-1})^2+F_{n}(x_{n}+x_{n-1})^2$,can you post your  more idea?

Comment: Because I think this is very very key,

Comment: @communnites That is all explained here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3611070/bound-on-matrix-product-beginbmatrix-1-frac1n-1-1-0-endbmatri/3615062#3615062 In short: its motivated by the corresponding continuous problem, i.e. that the recurrence is a discretisation of an ODE that is very common in physics (a ball attached to a spring). The $E_n$ is related to the energy of that system. In the linked question I do the analysis of the continuous problem and use the results of this to motivate the treatment of this problem.

Answer (score 13):

Very interesting problem. A possible approach to the solution is through the theory of dynamical systems considering it as a perturbation of a conservative system. I guess that the solution below might be improved to provide a slightly better constant.

Setting $y_n=x_{n-1}$ the given equation is equivalent to
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
y_{n+1} = x_n\\
x_{n+1} = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)x_n-y_n
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Consider the following energy function for the system
$$
E_n = (x_n + y_n)^2+3(x_n-y_n)^2.
$$
Using the definition of $x_{n+1}$ and $y_{n+1}$ above, a somehow lengthy, but straightforward computation gives
$$
E_{n+1} = E_n + \frac{4}{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)x_n^2 - \frac{8}{n}x_ny_n = E_n + \frac{4 x_n^2}{n^2} + \frac{4}{n} \left(x_n (x_n-y_n) -x_ny_n\right).
$$
Recalling that $x_n-y_n = x_{n+1}-\frac{1}{n}x_n$, this implies that
$$
E_{n+1} = E_n + \frac{4}{n} (x_{n+1}x_n - x_n y_n)
$$
and hence
$$
\begin{align}
E_{n+1} &= E_2 + \sum_{i=2}^n \frac{4}{i} (x_{i+1} y_{i+1} -x_iy_i) = E_2 + \frac{4}{n} x_{n+1} y_{n+1}+\sum_{i=3}^{n} \left( \frac{4}{i-1} - \frac{4}{i} \right)x_{i}y_{i} - 2x_2y_2\\
&=4+\frac{4}{n} x_{n+1} y_{n+1} + \sum_{i=3}^{n} \frac{4}{i(i-1)} x_{i}y_{i}
\end{align}
$$
where in the last passage we used $x_2 = 1$ and $y_2 = 0$.

Observing that $E_{n} \geq (x_n+y_n)^2+(x_n-y_n)^2 = 2(x_n^2+y_n^2)$ we deduce
$$
2(x_{n+1}^2 + y_{n+1}^2) \leq E_{n+1} \leq  4 + \frac{2}{n}(x_{n+1}^2 + y_{n+1}^2)+\sum_{i=3}^{n} \frac{2(x_i^2 + y_i^2)}{i(i-1)}
$$
or
$$
x_{n+1}^2 + y_{n+1}^2 \leq 4 +\sum_{i=3}^{n} \frac{2(x_i^2 + y_i^2)}{i(i-1)}
$$

We now want to apply Gronwall's discrete lemma to this equation (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325565/gronwalls-lemma-discrete-version)). Recalling
$$
\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\frac{2}{i(i+1)} = 1
$$
we prove $x_n^2 \leq 4e$ which shows that the desired sequence is bounded despite with a worse constant than asked.

P.S.: Numerical inspection in the $(x,y)$ plane above suggests the optimal bound to be $x_n^2 \leq \frac{9}{4}$

P.P.S.: I was asked to add some insights on how the argument was developed. The techniques used are quite common in the analysis of ODEs. A good, undergraduate, introduction to some of the ideas below can be found in "Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos" by Strogatz ([link)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0738204536). I am not aware of thorough accessible works specifically dedicated to multidimensional discrete dynamical systems (which often arise though as Poincarè maps of higher dimensional systems of ODEs) since already the one-dimensional case gives rise to several tough problems.

Concerning the main steps of the argument:

- The transformation into a first order system is a common trick.
- Direct inspection of the "unperturbed" system (i.e. the one without the $1/n$ term) shows that all sequences generated by arbitrary $x_1$ and $x_2$ are 6-periodic. Hence the idea to look for an almost conserved quantity for the given case. Some educated guessing supported by simulation led to the definition of the "energy" $E_n$ above which is conserved up to $O(\frac{1}{n})$ terms.
- Gronwall's technique is finally standard tool in the field. However, in this case some pre-work was needed on the energy estimate to leave only converging terms (hence the somehow painful rearrangement and index shift in the latest steps).

Comment: It seems so elegant.

Comment: How do you deduce $2(x_{n+1}^2 + y_{n+1}^2) \leq E_{n+1}$ from $E_{n+1}=4+\frac{4}{n} x_{n+1} y_{n+1} + \sum_{i=3}^{n} \frac{4}{i(i-1)} x_{i}y_{i}$ ? What makes the $\sum_{i=3}^{n} \frac{4}{i(i-1)} x_{i}y_{i}$ terms magically disappear ?

Comment: How do you think about, can you put your thoughts and thought process written down so I can learn it, thank you,and it's nice answer+1

Comment: @EwanDelanoy,because $E_{n+1}=(x_{n+1}+y_{n+1})^2+3(x_{n+1}-y_{n+1})^2\ge (x_{n+1}+y_{n+1})^2+(x_{n+1}-y_{n+1})^2=2(x^2_{n+1}+y^2_{n+1})$

Comment: Where did $4e$ come about? What happened to the $2$? Also, why is Stefano considering $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i(i+1)}$ instead of $\sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac{1}{i(i+1)}$?

Comment: @mathworker21 The intermediate step is wrong, but the final result is correct : the correct sum is $\sum_{i=3}^{\infty} \frac{2}{i(i-1}}=\sum_{j=2}^{\infty} \frac{2}{j(j+1}}=2\times \frac{1}{2}=1$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy haha ok

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: You are right on the estimate on $E_n $ from below. I edited the answer for higher clarity. On your second question it is straightforward to prove $4x_iy_i \leq 2x_i^2 + 2y_i^2$ .

Comment: @communnites: I added a post scriptum explaining the origin of my argument. Hope this helps and provides some interesting sources for further exploration on the subject!

Comment: @mathworker21: Thank you for pointing out this. I have corrected the passage for clarity.

Comment: Just a note that this approach generates a whole sequence of bounds by moving terms of the sum into the $\alpha$ part before applying Gronwall's inequality. The best bound proven by this approach appears to be approximately $6.301356,$ down from $4e \approx 10.873$ but still quite away from $9/4.$

Comment: For the continuous problem $\ddot{x} + w^2(t) x = 0$ defining the energy to be $E = \frac{1}{2}\dot{x}^2 + \frac{1}{2}w^2(t)x^2$ we have $\dot{E} \geq 0$ and $\dot{E} \leq \frac{2\dot{w}}{w} E$ so $E$ is strictly increasing and can be bounded (so it converges) by Gronwall to be $E(t_0) \leq E(t) \leq E(t_0) w^2(t)/w^2(t_0)$. (...)

Comment: (…) A discrete equivalent with the same properties would be $E_n = \frac{1}{2}(x_n - x_{n-1})^2 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{w_n^2}{1 - w_n^2/4}(\frac{x_n + x_{n-1}}{2})^2$. This converges and $w_n \to 1$ and using that its just an ellipse (for which we can compute the max of the sum of the two coordinates) and it follows that $x_n^2 \leq 2E_{\rm max}$ asymptotically and computing the first few values numerically one can get $E\leq 1$ so $x_2^2=9/4$ is indeed the maximum if I didn’t make any mistakes. This is just tedious work though and doesn’t really add much (its the method that is interesting here).

Answer (score 2):

(Too long for a comment)

Let $S_0 = 0, \ S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k.$ Then applying summation by parts to the formula

$$ x_{n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{x_{k}}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}x_{k}$$

yields the equation (for $n\geq 2$)

$$ x_{n+1} = 1 + \frac{S_n}{n} - S_{n-1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{S_k}{k(k+1)}$$

Adding $S_n$ to both sides of this also gives

$$S_{n+1} = 1 + \frac{S_n}{n} + x_n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{S_k}{k(k+1)}$$

I attempted to use these equations together with an inductive hypothesis of the form $S_{n-1} \in [a,b] , x_n \in [c,d]$ to show that $x_{n+1}, S_{n+1}$ must also lie in the same bounds. While you can get extremely close, it never quite works out and I've convinced myself that this method can not succeed no matter with choices we make for $a,b,c,d.$

However, using an established a bound $|x_n| \leq M$ (such as the one Stefano proved above) then we can prove inductively that $S_n$ is also bounded.

**Conjecture** - The sequence $S_n$ approaches a limit $L,$ and $$L = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{S_n}{n(n+1)} \approx 1.953053682$$
A corollary of this is that $x_n \to 0,$ which it appears to do so very very slowly.

Comment: I think the limit is not correct. Instead, it approaches 1.9735... - but the graph looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/mu4Zg2f